# how to compare two mysql table in php

Tags: php, mysql

i have a movie table and i want to compare the common movies of two users.

```
$array1=array();
$array2=array();
$query2="select name from movie where user_id='2'";
$result2=mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
while($rss = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result2))
{
    $array1[]=$rss;
}
print_r($array1);
```

This will print

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Snatch ) [1] => Array ( [name] => The Social Network Movie )
[2] => Array ( [name] => Death Note ) [3] => Array ( [name] => Titanic ) 
[4] => Array ( [name] => Once Upon a Time in the West ) )
```

And for second user

```
$query3="select name from movie where user_id=1";
$result3=  mysql_query($query3) or die(mysql_error());
while($rss1=  mysql_fetch_assoc($result3))
{
    $array2[]=$rss1;
}
print_r($array2);
```

This will print

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => The Lord of the Rings Trilogy ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Snatch ) 
[2] => Array ( [name] => The Social Network Movie ) [3] => Array ( [name] => Scarface ) 
[4] => Array ( [name] => Once Upon a Time in the West ) [5] => Array ( [name] => Legend of the Guardians: The Owls of Ga'Hoole ) [6] => Array ( [name] => Once Upon a Time in America ) 
[7] => Array ( [name] => Butch Cassidy and the Sundance Kid ) [8] => Array ( [name] => Fracture ) 
[9] => Array ( [name] => Invictus ) [10] => Array ( [name] => Pride and Glory ) [11] => Array ( [name] => Casablanca ) )
```

When i compare these two arrays it gives me the first array.

```
$match= array_intersect($array1, $array2);
print_r($match);
```

The result will is

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Snatch ) [1] => Array ( [name] => The Social Network Movie )
[2] => Array ( [name] => Death Note ) [3] => Array ( [name] => Titanic ) 
[4] => Array ( [name] => Once Upon a Time in the West ) )
```

**But the Common movies are:** `Snatch , The social network movie , once upon a time in the west`

Comment: Why don't you do that in mysql?

Comment: Did you copy/paste this code directly from your source? Here you have $query3 pulling from the same user_id as $query2, so of course it would just print out everything in $array1

Comment: @zerkms: Because of poor DB design

Comment: @tkm256 sorry in query2 its `user_id=2` not `1`

Comment: @Shakti Singh : How can i make strong db design in this scenario in which i want to compare the common movies of two users.  what do you suggest....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing the following instead

`while($rss = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result2))
{
    $array1[]=$rss['name'];
}`

That way the values in the arrays will be strings and can be compared easily. I don't know of the top of my head how array_intersect handles nested arrays but it works fine with strings.